# Infinite scroll with AJAX POST fires multiple times instead of 1

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, lazy-loading

I have been following the tutorial for creating infinite scroll / lazy load.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi1S-BpoMQY&feature=youtu.be

I have everything working except that when I scroll then AJAX fires POST multiple times instead of 1.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var page_num = 1;
load_page(page_num, false);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        page_num++;
        load_page(page_num, false)
    }
  }); 
});


function load_page(page_num, loading) {
if (loading == false) {
    loading = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action/post.php',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            page_num: page_num
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#ajax-loader').show();
            return;
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
        loading = false;
        $("#dynamic-posts").append(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in document.height - 100. I changed it to 50 and it started to work. Anything more than 80 breaks the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that variable loading alway is false, because is send as parameters.
I moved the scope variable loading. It help send 1 ajax by time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var page_num = 1;
var loading = false;
load_page(page_num);


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        page_num++;
        load_page(page_num)
    }
  }); 
});


function load_page(page_num) {
if (loading == false) {
    loading = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action/post.php',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            page_num: page_num
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#ajax-loader').show();
            return;
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
        loading = false;
        $("#dynamic-posts").append(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
        loading = false;
    });
 }
}
```